# Conditionally render JSF components for printing

Tags: jsf, printing, conditional-rendering

I want to print only a certain part of my webpage (so not the whole page). How can I achieve this in JSF?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is normally to be controlled by CSS with `display: none|block`. Check the [CSS media rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html).

For example, as `@media print {}` inside a default CSS file:

```css
@media print {
    #header, #footer, #menu { 
        display: none;
    }
}
```

*(the above example will hide HTML elements with IDs `header`, `footer` and `menu`)*

Or via a generic style class:

```css
@media screen {
    .printonly { 
        display: none;
    }
}

@media print {
    .noprint { 
        display: none;
    }
    .printonly { 
        display: block;
    }
}
```

You then add `styleClass="noprint"` to those which you'd like to hide from print, and `styleClass="printonly"` to those which you'd like to show in print only.

You can also put the print specific CSS in its own stylesheet file and reference it using `<link media="print">` or `<h:outputStylesheet media="print">` as below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/css/print.css" media="print" />
<!-- Or -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="#{resource['css/print.css']}" media="print" />
<!-- Or -->
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/print.css" media="print" />
```

```css
#header, #footer, #menu { 
    display: none;
}
```

Noted shoud be that `<h:outputStylesheet media>` attribute was only added in JSF 2.1, so if you're still on JSF 2.0, consider upgrading to at least 2.1 (should be 100% compatible without any code and configuration changes in the webapp itself). Otherwise just go for the plain HTML `<link>` approach.

Comment: My IDE tells me there is no `media` attribute on `<h:outputStylesheet>`. Is the `media` attribute version specific? I'm on `com.sun.faces` version `2.1.18`.

Comment: [Your IDE is wrong](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputStylesheet.html).

Comment: Yeah, it's works just fine. I'll send Netbeans a bug report. +1

Comment: @JasperdeVries I suppose that this is caused by a missing `<attribute>` entry in `html_basic.taglib.xml`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via pure CSS by specifying media type: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html