# How to print out uploaded text JSF

Tags: jsf

I have now managed to create an upload in jsf that allows the user to upload a txt file, I can also display what has been uploaded, what I need to know now is how can I print this text to a printer when a user presses a command button

Thanks

I have added create a new css file called print.css,

```
@media print {
    #header, #footer, #menu, #title, #h1, #2, #main, #logo, #logo_text, #logo_colour, #site_content, #content{ 
        display: none;
    }
}
```

As these are the things I wish removed

My css for the whole document is:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" title="style" />
```

I have added:

```
<h:outputStylesheet type="text/css" name="print.css" media="print" />
```

above my button :

```
                <button onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
```

but when I press this button I can still see all the css

Comment: Which printer? The one of the client or the one of the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can at most show up the browser's print dialog by JS `window.print()`.

```
<button onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
```

This will still require confirmation of the enduser. It's for websites (fortunately) simply not possible to unaskingly print something. That would otherwise produce a lot of paper waste and annoyed clients.

You might perhaps want to supply a print media CSS along so that *only* the desired content is been printed and that the remnant is been hidden by `display:none`. You can find some hints in this related question: [Conditionally render JSF components for printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248280/printing-webpage-in-jsf).

Comment: so if i was wanting to print only what is in the inputTextarea, would the css you linked still be the best way to do this

Comment: Im sorry, i don't understand how upon the press of the print button the css way works, could it explain it for me , sorry i am very new to all this still

Comment: Just supply the CSS file with desired `@media` rules by `<link rel="stylesheet">` or `<h:outputStylesheet>` with `media="print"` in the very same webpage as the button is placed. Exactly as explained (and linked) in the related question.

Comment: I have update the original question with some issues i am currently having

Comment: Where exactly do you "still see all that CSS"? On the print preview or on the printed page? By the way, the `@media print {}` block is not necessary when the CSS file itself is already served via `media="print"`. It's only necessary when including in the default CSS.

Comment: Did the browser successfully retrieve the `print.css` file?

Comment: Silly question - how can i find that out ?

Comment: WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, print.css.

Comment: Just look at the HTTP traffic monitor (press F12 in Chrome/IE9/Firebug), or the server log in case you're using `<h:outputStylesheet>` instead. Well, it turns out that its URL is wrong, or that you placed it at the wrong location, or that it's not properly deployed.

Comment: it is in the same location as my main .css file and have added the these into the original question, will double check

Comment: Ok i have successfully managed to remove all the css, but i still have text and buttons around the inputTextarea, can these be removed too?

Comment: Yes, by using CSS the right way. Add a selector on those elements with `display:none`. Please ask a new question if you still stucks. Please note that the concrete CSS problem is **unrelated** to JSF.